# BeagleBone Black PRU overlay Syntax error

Tags: linux, debian, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I try to use beagle bone black pru according the "Exploring BeagleBone" book (Derek Moloy) 
[image: Exploring BeagleBone page 511]

I have cloned the github repristory of this book and I try to use that overlay but I have a syntax error. 
[image: my Console]

I don't know what is the reason of this error.

Comment: Please edit your Q to show your real code, (not from a book, you may have a transcription error) AND don't use screen shots on stackOverflow to describe your problem. Expert readers expect to be able to search postings in their browser for specific terms, syntax etc. They can't do that on a screen shot. Use the `{}` tool on the edit menu on selected text to format correctly as code/data/error messages. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That book was written some time ago and thus expects things to be in the way they were at that time. You will need to reenable 'capemanager'. This is covered in the [official wiki](https://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#Where_did_the_slots_file_go.3F).

Another aspect of current images is that you will need to choose between `UIO` and `remoteproc` for communicating with the PRU.

- `/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-UIO-00A0.dtbo`
- `/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-RPROC-*-00A0.dtbo` (replace * by correct kernel version reference)

Unless that example from the book contains the necessary parts already.